Behaviour of $\cot^{-1}\cfrac{\sqrt{1+\sin x} + \sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1+\sin x} - \sqrt{1-\sin x}}$
$$
\operatorname{arccot}\left(\cfrac{\sqrt{1+\sin x} + \sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1+\sin x} - \sqrt{1-\sin x}}\right)
$$

Why does this function equal to $x/2$ for $x \in \left(0, \pi/4\right)$, and equal to $\pi/2 - x/2$ for $x \in \left(\pi/2,\pi\right)$ ?.
I've checked this with a graphing calculator. I also tried to simplify the function, but I'm getting both $x/2$ and $\pi/2 - x/2$, which I know is not possible.


Let us define $$y:= \cfrac{\sqrt{1+\sin x} + \sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1+\sin x} - \sqrt{1-\sin x}} = \frac{\left|\cos x\right| + 1}{\sin x}$$
When $x \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}2\right)$, $\cos x>0$. So $y=\frac{\cos x + 1}{\sin x} = \cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$. One usually defines the principal branch of $\cot^{-1}$ in $(0, \pi)$. So in this case, the expression becomes $$\cot^{-1} y = \frac{x}2$$
For $x \in \left(\frac{\pi}2, \pi\right)$, $\cos x<0$. Then $y=\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x} = \tan\left(\frac{x}2\right) = \cot\left(\frac{\pi}2 - \frac{x}2\right)$ and again since $0<\frac{\pi}2-\frac{x}2 < \frac{\pi}4$, one has $$\cot^{-1} y = \frac{\pi}2 - \frac{x}2$$
